# Proper fscanf in C

Tags: c, file

This is input: Francetic, Petra#13/12/1930 Trg zrtava Uskoka 156 (Skopje) 800893452/2008

It wont fscanf properly it show's m=0 and that's how I know that while loop was not successful.

```
while(fscanf(mrtvaciTxt, "%[^,],%[^#]#%d/%d/%d %[^0-9]%d (%[^)]) %[^/]/%[^\n] ",


            &pomrli[m].prezime, &pomrli[m].ime, 
&pomrli[m].dan,&pomrli[m].mjesec,&pomrli[m].godina, &pomrli[m].adresa,&pomrli[m].brUlice,
                  &pomrli[m].brOsobne, &pomrli[m].godSmrti  )== 9)
    {
        m++;
    }
        printf("%d\n\n", m);
```

How can I fscanf this and is there any tutorial how can i be better at this because it takes me so much time.

Francetic

Petra

13

12

1930

Trg zrtava Uskoka 156 (Skopje)

800893452

2008, I want fscanf to look like this

Comment: Can you please describe what issue you are having with your code as shown?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It's safer to [use `fgets()` to read a line from the file, then `sscanf()` (or otherwise parse) that line](https://ideone.com/RqfGRd): basically `while (fgets()) { sscanf(); }`

Comment: I have to use fscanf because I need parts of it for later.

Comment: The part of scanf that looks wrong is `%[^\n]%*[\n] %[^)])%*s%[^/]/%d`. The first `%[^\n]` will accept the rest of the input line up to the `\n`. This is obviously not what you want since you still want to parse fields afterwards. It is unclear where the `adresa` field should end. Could you tell us where you want your fields to be split ?

Comment: Francetic Petra 13 12 1930 Trg zrtava Uskoka 156 (Skopje) 800893452 2008, I want fscanf to look like this

Comment: Please turn your shown code fragment into a [mre].

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ I.e. try to fix by only reading the first part until it works, then go after the second. Start from scratch if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple errors in the scanf format.

Here is the correct scanf format string:

```
" %[^,], %[^#]#%d/%d/%d %[^(](%[^)]) %[^/]/%d"
```

Here is the list of errors:

- there are 11 % while you expect only 9 fields
- lacking a space in front of the format string to consume the newline
- there is a / in front of the first %d which shouldn’t be there
- you are using a [^\n] where you should use [^(]( for the adresa
- you are using %*[\n] for unknown reason
- you should use [^)] to get the grad
- etc.

you modified you question, so I don’t know what else you did.